# Generate back stack for deep linking from an email URL

Tags: android, deep-linking, back-stack

I basically try to mix these two tutorials:

- [deep linking from notification with back stack](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)
- [deep linking from url](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

What I want to do is to launch a specific activity of my app when the user click on a url in an email. When the activity is launched I want the user to be able to press back and to go to the parent activity like if the user had land on this page following the normal journey throw the app.

I know how to open the specific activity but I don't know how to generate the backstack. In the example they are able to manage the backstack as the deep linking comes from a notification generated by the app itself, so they can create a pending intent. In my case the link is from an email so I can't do that.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html ? They recomend there to use `startActivities` to provide back stack for deep links.

Comment: It's a similar tuto to the links I put above. The example is for a notification. As the notification is generated by the app itself you can create a pending intent. But in the case your intent filter respond to an url there is no pending intent defined. They're talking about NavUtils, do you think I should use that instead?

Comment: In my projects I have activity without content view for handling incoming intents. This `RouterActivity` handles intents and decides what activities should be started with `startActivities` after that it finishes itself with `finish()`. As this activity does not have any layout and is finished in `onCreate` user has no clue that there was any activity started before desired one.

Comment: I like this idea and this is what I was trying to implement yesterday afternoon, but how do you prevent a blank screen to pop before the activity you want to display? Because even if the RouterActivity doesn't have a layout it still pops. At the moment my code is like that: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
  TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
    .addParentStack(MyActivity.class)
    .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class))
    .startActivities();
 }
 finish();
}`

Comment: What if you call `finish()` before `startActivities()` ? Does it still pops?

Comment: Yes it does still pop.

Comment: Check with this theme: `@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay` and use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` in your `RouterActivtiy`.

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks! Can you please write an answer to the question, so like that I can approve it?

Comment: In my project it were not poping propably becouse I had `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>` in my application theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create activity without content view for handling incoming intents. This `RouterActivity` handles intents and decides what activities should be started with `startActivities` (TaskStackBuilder) after that it finishes itself with `finish()`.

`RouterActivity` should use theme: `@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay` (use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`) and should not set any content view 
 so user will have no clue that there was any activity started before desired one.